# Parse String into Java Objects

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jdbc, amazon-athena

I need to convert `String`s of this format into an `Array` of objects.

```
[{name=Nancy Chapman, email=nchapman0@comcast.net}, {name=Jimmy Fisher, email=jfisher1@photobucket.com}]
```

Is there any easy way to convert this without having to do it completely manually?

UPDATE: 
I am pulling these values from a custom SQL database (Amazon Athena). And the custom `JDBC` does not support `getArray()` so it looks like I need to manually parse the columns that contain an `Array` of `Structs`. It is unfortunately a limitation of the DB and I have no control over it. This is the format the SQL database returns when I call `getString()` on the column.

SQL Table Definition

```
 id (int)
 threadid (int)
 senderemail (string)
 sendername (string)
 subject (string)
 body (string)
 recipients (array<struct<name:string,email:string>>)
 ccrecipients (array<struct<name:string,email:string>>)
 bccrecipients (array<struct<name:string,email:string>>)
 attachments (array<binary>)
 date (timestamp)
```

Java Objects

`MessageObj`

```
public class MessageObj {

private int id;
private int threadId;
private String senderEmail;
private String senderName;
private String subject;
private String body;
private List<RecipientObj> recipients;
private List<RecipientObj> ccRecipients;
private List<RecipientObj> bccRecipients;
private List<File> attachments;
private Calendar date;
}
```

`RecipientObj`

```
public class RecipientObj {
private String email;
private String name;
}
```

Parsing the data.

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

while (rs.next()) {
// Retrieve table column.
int id = rs.getInt("id");
Integer threadId = rs.getInt("threadid");
String senderEmail = rs.getString("senderemail");
String senderName = rs.getString("sendername");
String subject = rs.getString("subject");
String body = rs.getString("body");

//How to convert recipients into ArrayList? rs.getArray("recipients") not supported.
//... Code here to add into an ArrayList of MessageObj.
}
```

Comment: Why are your inputs in this format? Where are they coming from? It looks kind of like mangled JSON; was JSON involved?

Comment: [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)?

Comment: Is there a name for the format? If it's common, there's probably a library for it, otherwise you will either have to do it manually or use a different format.

Comment: Why not iterate through the ResultSet to create the array of objects? Also using frameworks like Hibernate will make it easier for mapping values from DB to objects.

Comment: @Kenpachi can you provide an example? I am already iterating through the `ResultSet`. This is a column in a row being processed.

Comment: @Alan name and email are different columns right. Please provide a sample schema and sample code for how you are iterating through the ResultSet. That would be much helpful

Comment: @Kenpachi added.

Comment: @Alan I believe you will have to do the data binding manually. since Athena is a Big Data data server, Hibernate or any other JPA frameworks wont work. So you might need to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question but what you typed should work if you clean it up a bit so that it looks like this:

```
[{ name:"Nany Chapman", email:"nchapman0@comcast.net"}, 
{ name:"Nany Chapman", email:"nchapman0@comcast.net"}]
```

Rather than use the equal sign, use a colon and put quotation marks around your values.

Comment: For it to be parsed as JSON, there also must be quotes around the keys.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot change the input to JSON. I wish I could so I could leverage libraries like `GSON`